# MVVM light EventToCommand: get selected item

Tags: mvvm, light, eventtocommand

I have a treeview where I can click on items. I am using MVVM light toolkit and the EventToCommand and would like to know which item was chosen. How can I pass this to my viewmodel?

```
<interact:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interact:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SimpleCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=mainTreeView}"
                                    />
            </interact:EventTrigger>
       </interact:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/#intro With the newest version, you can get the EventArgs of the fired event directly in the ViewModel to handle it.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me from asking the same question